# How To Save Appllication State And Restore It AGAIN

Tags: ios, objective-c

i use navigation controller , i have 6  navigation controller i want the app to save state and restore the last screen the application terminate on . to open it when it launch again
what is the code i must use to do that in any view .

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718341/ios-6-saving-restoring-app-state-feature

Answer (score 5):

Apple provides mechanisms to do this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches?language=objc

The important bits from the link:

> State preservation and restoration is not an automatic feature and
>   apps must opt-in to use it. Apps indicate their support for the
>   feature by implementing the following methods in their app delegate:
>
> ```
> application:shouldSaveApplicationState:
> application:shouldRestoreApplicationState:
> ```
>
> Normally, your implementations of these methods just return YES to
>   indicate that state preservation and restoration can occur. However,
>   apps that want to preserve and restore their state conditionally can
>   return NO in situations where the operations should not occur. For
>   example, after releasing an update to your app, you might want to
>   return NO from your application:shouldRestoreApplicationState: method
>   if your app is unable to usefully restore the state from a previous
>   version.
>
> **Preserving the State of Your View Controllers**
>
> Preserving the state of your app’s view controllers should be your
>   main goal. View controllers define the structure of your user
>   interface. They manage the views needed to present that interface and
>   they coordinate the getting and setting of the data that backs those
>   views. To preserve the state of a single view controller, you must do
>   the following:
>
> (Required) Assign a restoration identifier to the view controller; see
>   “Marking Your View Controllers for Preservation.” (Required) Provide
>   code to create or locate new view controller objects at launch time;
>   see “Restoring Your View Controllers at Launch Time.” (Optional)
>   Implement the encodeRestorableStateWithCoder: and
>   decodeRestorableStateWithCoder: methods to encode and restore any
>   state information that cannot be recreated during a subsequent launch;
>   see “Encoding and Decoding Your View Controller’s State.”
>
> In addition to the data preserved by your app’s view controllers and
>   views, UIKit provides hooks for you to save any miscellaneous data
>   needed by your app. Specifically, the UIApplicationDelegate protocol
>   includes the following methods for you to override:
>
> ```
> application:willEncodeRestorableStateWithCoder:
> application:didDecodeRestorableStateWithCoder:
> ```

Comment: Dear : I See The Documentation & a lot Of material But That Doesn't Success please Notify Me How To Do That

Comment: It's usually nice to include some information in your answer and not just a link so that if the link breaks (and it will) there's still something helpful.

Comment: I just fixed the link :)